# Listview to another layout. Is it possible?

Tags: android, string, listview

I am a beginner. How will my string can be a clickable one that can redirect to other layout. or different layouts.

EDITED
This is my `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String[] country = new String[] {
        "China",
        "India",
        "Sri Lanka",
        "Malaysia",
        "Japan",
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_layout, country);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PageOne.class);

            startActivity(in);
        };
    });

}
```

and This is the PageOne.class

```
public class PageOne extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.china);
    getIntent().getStringExtra("China");
  }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
  }
```

I wanted to do is when India is Click it will go to India.xml
And if China is click it will go to China.xml but what happening is any String I click the result is china.xml.

Comment: Do u want to make your listview clickable,how can a string be clickable ., what context is it displaying ?

Comment: I just wanted if I click the "India" it will go to another layout "India.java" or "India.class".. But I don't have any idea

Comment: com.example.android.chuck.PageOne should be com.tmm.android.chuck.PageOne. Cross the same in manifest

Comment: @immaBeans check the manifest file and change this  Intent i= new Intent("com.example.android.chuck.PageOne"); to  Intent i= new Intent("com.tmm.android.chuck.PageOne");

Answer (score 0):

Assume you want listview row which contains strings to be clickable.

```
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             Intent i= new Intent("com.example.secondactivity");
                             i.putExtra("value",  country[arg2]);
                             // pass country based on listview position 
                             //value- is the key
                             // second parameter is the actual value ie country name 
                             startActivity(i);

        }


    });
```

country[arg2] . arg2 is the position of the listview. Items in listview are populated based on the position. When listview row is clicked country[arg2] is name of the country in that listview position. So you pass the value to the secondactivity using intent.

To retrieve in Second Activity's onCreate()

```
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
     String country = b.getString(key);//value or china in youe case.
```

Make sure second activity has an entry in manifest file

EDIT:

```
  <activity
   android:name="com.example.test1.secondactivity"
   >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.example.test1.secondactivity" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

MainActivity with listview.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String[] country = new String[] {
"India",
"Pakistan",
"Sri Lanka",
"China",
"Bangladesh",
"Nepal",
"Afghanistan",
"North Korea",
"South Korea",
"Japan"
};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// R.layout.listview_layout is the custom layout
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, country);
 //this refers to the actiivty context,
 //second parameters says its a simple list item
 //third is id of text 
 //country is your array of string    
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{



    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        Intent i= new Intent("com.example.test1.secondactivity");
        i.putExtra("value",  country[arg2]);
        // pass country based on listview position 
        //value- is the key
        // second parameter is the actual value ie country name 
        startActivity(i);

    }


}); 
}
}
```

Second Actiivty which has a textview.

```
    public class secondactivity extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String country = extras.getString("value");//value or china in youe case
        tv.setText(country);
    }

  }
  }
```

Project folder

[image]

Comment: Mr. Raghunandan, thank you for this but is that Strings can navigate me to another layout?and how? Im confused, sorry Im just a beginner. 
And what is "com.example.secondactivity"?

Comment: arg2 is the position in the listview. country[arg2] is name of the country in that listview position. So when clicked you can pass the string value to another activity called ssecondactivity which is under the package com.example. You are passing value to the second activity using intent

Comment: I understand now.. :)
Intent i= new Intent("com.example.IndiaActivity");
i.putExtra("India",  country[arg2]);
startActivity(i);

The "value" is the name of the string? that I wanted? if the layout is com.example.ChinaActivity . Can I change the value of "value" with "China"?

Comment: yes. its just a key. you can change. in second activity you can receive values using bundle.

Comment: wow. I will try this at home. this is cool thank you. another question. Mr. Raghunandan what is bundle?

Comment: I have already ChinaActivity.java, AM I going to put the codes under onCreate method of this class? and in "String country = b.getString(key);" thus the "key" will be replace by china?

Comment: yes replace key with "china". also replace "value" by "china" in the activity where you try to pass value. Actually you can name the key as countries in general.

Comment: I have error here "listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()"

Comment: edit your question and post the logcat along with the code. What is the error?

Comment: Mr. Raghunandan, this is spoon feeding thank you for helping beginner like me. I just edit the code.

Comment: Sir can I use "this, PageOne.class" instead of "Intent i= new Intent("com.tmm.android.chuck.PageOne");"?

Comment: yes. Explicit intents. http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for.html

Comment: there still error in my part. I dont know if it is the adapter because I dont know where is "simple_list_item_1" and "text1" or in second class or I'm just stupid :(

Comment: the first one is the default layout for listview. com.example.test1 is the package name under the source folder of your project. secondactivity is the activity name

Comment: check the edit posted a screenshot. as you can see com.example.test1 is the package name and mainactivity and seconactivity are under the same package.

Comment: sir please check the edited question. It still have an error I dont get the adapter part "(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, country);"

Comment: for me your code looks fine. Have you imported the right import statements? and cross check your manifest file if you have made a entry for the activities

Comment: Yes sir. If you have time sir, May you look upon my codes? here the link (https://www.facebook.com/ajax/messaging/attachment.php?attach_id=15e9f72faa6ec217aaf287c1f1332d83&mid=mid.1364911264825%3Adcd7b0bf654ef36b91&hash=AQCc3Omm35KTSdGC)

Comment: I posted the link for the image of the logcat. Do you receive my codes?

Comment: Looks like your activity does not have a entry in manifest file. Post your manifest file

Comment: Sir i cant post images, I need to have 15 reputation to post image. and the codes is my zip file. it is just 1mb

Answer (score 0):

You need to use base adapter for that, and open another activity an click of the row.

[Example](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/how-to-use-baseadapter-and-onitemclicklistener-in-android/)

you can also use listview onitem click listener

and open the respective activity with respect to the position.

Comment: This is cool Mr. zaiff but my goal is to go to another layout, not just to make TOAST. But now I have an idea about that kind of technique, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a listener on your list view item and navigate by intent to next activity.

```
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

            startActivity(in);
        };
    });
```

Comment: Am I going to put this on MainActivity.java? Do I need to create new method for that? (Sorry im just a beginner) But I understand the codes. I'll try this at home. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Kamil. I jus going to try this when I got home. I dont make any changes in Secondactivity? Are there any codes n second actvity? just the call of china.xml or what so ever layout?

Comment: Don't understand what you are trying to say? Just try to get value of country in second activity like `getIntent.getStringExtra("value");`

Comment: Mr kamil. thank you it is now working but, when India is Click it also go to china.xml.. it supposed to go to india.xml

Comment: @immaBeans I think you must accept this answer first if it helps,and ask a new question for that.